# Count and show how many times a line is duplicated in a file

Tags: python, search, duplicates, find

I have seen solutions for this in bash (i.e. question 6712437), but I haven't found any for python.

I am trying to search a file, find the duplicate lines and output how many times it is duplicated.

input

```
foo
bar
foo
foo
bar
foobar
```

output

```
foo     3
bar     2
foobar  1
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you looked into `Counter`, from `collections`?

Comment: Do you know how to open and read a file as a list of strings? Do you know how to use a dict in a loop?

Comment: @JordanSinger I have used counter before with re.findall for various things, but mostly with searching specific things/regex patterns.. I couldn't think of a way to apply it to searching duplicates.. I'm not CS, so learning as I search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`collections.Counter` seems like a good option.

To count the number of occurences of each line in a file you could try:

```
import collections

with open('myfile.txt') as f:
    c = collections.Counter(f.readlines())
```

Then, for nice output (like you asked for in a comment to this answer), you could use:

```
# sorted by value (number of occurences, but descending order)
for k, v in c.most_common():
    print(k, v)

# sorted by value (number of occurences, ascending order)
for k, v in sorted(c.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]):
    print(k, v)

# sorted by key (line of the file)
for k, v in sorted(c.items(), key=lambda x: x[0]):
    print(k, v)
```

Comment: thanks, this works.. i added to the script to post-process and create new lines, etc. so it's easier to read.. j/w is there another way to have it initially write with new lines?

Comment: I don't understand what you need. Could you add your script to your question (or ask a new question) and explain it in more detail?

Comment: sorry let me explain better.. with `collections.counter` the output is like `Counter ({'FOO\n': 17097, 'BAR\n': 16512, 'FOOBAR\n': 16154,.......`, as expected, and the way I make this usable is to convert to a string, write to document, then insert new lines, replace characters, etc. to format it.. I was wondering if there is a "better" way

Comment: @physlexic I edited my answer to add ways to nicely format the result

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution would be using `collections.Counter`. But, if you do not want to include an extra library then

```
d={}
with open('test.txt') as f:
    for i in f:
        d[i]=d.get(i,0)+1

    sorted_items = sorted(d.items(),key=lambda (k,v): (v,k),reverse=True)
    #iterate to save or play around with tuple values
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's my solution:

```
lines = [] #List of line items
itemcounts = {}  #dictionary of items with counts
with open('myfile.txt') as f: 
    for item in f:
        lines.append(item)
for i in lines:
    c = lines.count(i) 
    itemcounts.update({i:c})
#print items and counts
for i in itemcounts: 
    print i, itemcounts[i]
```